# Increvement var when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this array

```
var sizes =[
            ['300x250', 0],
            ['160x600', 0],
            ['728x90', 0],
            ['300x600', 0] 
        ];
```

I have many checkboxes , I want when i select one increment the value on my array, if I unselected decrement that value.

Till now I have this

```
var $checkboxes = $('#addA td input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function () {
    var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.checkbox:checked').value;
                    var ss = $(this).attr('value').split('_')[0];
                    console.log(ss);
     });
});
```

I used the split, cause the size is on checkbox value.

So, i select checkbox with value ="300x250_aaaaaa" i increment the value to 1
i select another checkbox with value ="300x250_fdsfds" i increment the value, so i have total of 2.
i select another checkbox with value ="300x600_fdsssfds" i increment the value 1.
If I unselected i have to decrement.
With this example, my final array should be like this:

```
var sizes =[
                ['300x250', 2],
                ['160x600', 0],
                ['728x90', 0],
                ['300x600', 1] 
            ];
```

On array I have all possible values
My HTML table

```
<table id="add-a" class="ad dataTable no-footer" style="width: 1500px;" role="grid">
<thead>
  <tr role="row">
<th align="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Add?: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 59px;">Add?</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 94px;"> ID</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Size: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 247px;">Size</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_7a53936d" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_zzzzz" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">1</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even" style="background: navajowhite;">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fd6cb3e4" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_aaaa" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">2</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_503dd438" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_bbbb" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">3</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_d68b36ad" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_cccc" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">4</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_dd7ff4ea" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_dddd" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">5</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_456f96f3" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_eeee" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">6</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_09c16d50" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_ffff" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">7</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr></tbody>
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: How to do that @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Object` instead of array and instead of using `value.split`, you can use `data` tag(`data-value="320x200"`).

Following is the code depicting the same.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g8pne8mb/1/)

```js
var data = {
  '300x250': 0,
  '160x600': 0,
  '728x90': 0,
  '300x600': 0
}

function createCheckBoxes() {
  var _testKeys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  var html = "";
  var keys = Object.keys(data)

  _testKeys.forEach(function(item) {
    html += "<div class='group'>";
    html += "<h3>" + item.toUpperCase() + "</h3>"

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      html += "<input type='checkbox' data-value='" +
        keys[i] + "' class='chk' value=" + keys[i] + "_" + item + "/>" + keys[i];
    }

    html += "</div>"
  });

  $("#content").html(html);
}

function registerEvents() {
  // $(".checkbox").on("change", function() {   // With your html
  $(".chk").on("change", function() {
    
    // Consider only increment operation and set -ve value to decrement.
    var value = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : -1;
    
    // You can use you "value.split()" if not comfortable with data-value
    var key = $(this).data("value");
    console.log(key, value);
    
    // Update Value
    data[key] += value;
    printData();
  });
}

function printData() {
  $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(data, " ", 4));
}

createCheckBoxes();
registerEvents();
```

```css
.group {
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, thanks, but I didn't understand. I added my html table on the top.

Comment: On javascript I only need to calculate (increment, decrement) when selected or unselected checkbox. Please if you can help me to understand this, i would appreciate

Comment: It does what i want, but i'm having problems to separate it and to check the values it prints. Could you separate and change the printTable to HTML part? You have my table on the top

Comment: First add `data-value` tag in your checkbox. This will save you logic to split value. Second bind an event on `$(".checkbox").on("change", function(){})`. This will be generic handler for all checkboxes. Third, check is current value is checked or not? for this you can use `$(this).is(":checked")`. It will return true if checked. Then just update property in object

Comment: Also, you can ignore `createCheckBoxes()`. I like creating dynamic HTML. Saves me from typing entire HTML.:-) Also, if you want any further clarification, just drop a comment

Comment: Hi, i made some changes. https://jsfiddle.net/bk6jg519/1/ Can you tell me why I can't see the div result now? @Rajesh

Comment: You are missing `jQuery`. Check [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/bk6jg519/6/)

Comment: if i add this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> on my project. All my datatables stop work and i get a lot of errors

Comment: You can still use your previous jQuery that you were using.

Comment: im using 1.7.1. it is ok?

Comment: I can't pass it to my project, no idea why. even console.log doesn't work

Comment: Following is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/bk6jg519/14/) with jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an object?

```
var sizes={
 320x200: 0
}
```

Then you can increment it with something like:

```
var ss = $(this).attr('value').split('_')[0];
sizes[ss] += 1;
```

Comment: to change with object I agree, thanks. But didn't understand the rest, because it always increment, never decrement